# Javascript -- filter set of links and style

Tags: jquery

Here is my set of links:

```
<ul id="power">
    <li><a id="10watt" name="power" href="#">10 watt</a></li>
    <li><a id="25watt" name="power" href="#">25 watt</a>
    <li><a id="30watt" name="power" href="#">30 watt</a>
    <li><a id="40watt" name="power" href="#">40 watt</a>
    <li><a id="50watt" name="power" href="#">50 watt</a>
    <li><a id="60watt" name="power" href="#">60 watt</a>
    <li><a id="75watt" name="power" href="#">75 watt</a>
    <li><a id="100watt" name="power" href="#">100 watt</a>
    <li><a id="120watt" name="power" href="#">120 watt</a>
    <li><a id="150watt" name="power" href="#">150 watt</a>
</ul>
```

and then I have an array:

```
var nine = ['25watt','30watt','40watt','50watt','60watt','75watt'];
```

I want to filter the links so the ones not in the array are styled with the "unavailable" class defined in my CSS.  Here is my jQuery.

```
if (this.id == '93') {
           $('a [name="power"]').filter(function() {
               if ($.inArray($(this).attr('id'), nine) < 0)
               $(this).addClass('unavailable');
               $(this).removeAttr('href');
           });
      }
```

this.id comes from the previous set of links,  How do I write my filter statement, because what I have isn't working.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: is that the exact html? because it's missing some </li>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
$('a[name="power"]').filter(function() {
    return $.inArray($(this).attr('id'), nine) == -1;
}).addClass('unavailable').removeAttr('href');
```

Your selector had a space between `a` and `[name="power"]`, which means that you were selecting all `[name="power"]` that are descendants of `a`, not `a` itself. Besides that, i corrected the filter function to do the filtering only.

Comment: Thanks, but it doesn't work, at least not inside the if statement

Comment: @shummel7845: Does the interpreter reach that section of code? Is `this.id` equal to `93`?

Comment: OK, thanks.  It's only styling the first link.  Is there something wrong with my array?

Comment: Yes, I checked.  this.id is equal to 93